# Keras 2.0.0: how to access and modify the training data in the callback function "on_epoch_end()"?

Tags: callback, keras-2

I am using Keras 2.0.0 with Theano.

I would like to update the training data between each epoch. I can do it in a for loop using nb_epochs=1 but it would be much more elegant using the on_epoch_end callback.

Here is my tentative code, based on a Keras 1 example([blog post](https://keunwoochoi.wordpress.com/2016/07/16/keras-callbacks/)):

```
class callback_change_X_train(keras.callbacks.Callback):

def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    X_train = my_function_to_update_X_train(...)
    self.model.training_data[0] = X_train
```

Unfortunately, it seems that self.model.training_data does not exist anymore.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Just ran into this problem myself and solved it using the `model.fit_generator` method instead of the standard `fit` method. You can perform some modification to the data at each epoch this way. I'm not sure if you can get access to the `model` object itself this way, but for my problem I just needed to shuffle the data along one of the inner axes.

Example code:

```
def shuffle_gen(x_train, y_train):
    while True:
        shuffle_inner_axis(x_train, y_train)
        for b_i in range(steps_per_epoch):
            yield(x_train[b_i * batch_size:(b_i + 1) * batch_size],
                  y_train[b_i * batch_size:(b_i + 1) * batch_size])
    return

model.fit_generator(shuffle_gen(x_train, y_train), steps_per_epoch, n_epochs)
```

Comment: What is `b_i_1` defined as? And where is it defined?

Comment: Typo. Fixed to `b_i + 1`. Thanks.